# Box2d creating a massive body - split it up?

Tags: javascript, box2d

I am creating a space simulation, and this will require that I make planets, small ships and large ships.

I will be optimizing my small ships to equal about 1 m in the physics simulation, however, planets will probably be about ~1000m or larger in the simulation, and some of the largest ships might be 200m or larger as well.

As far as I know, box2d does not play nice with objects larger then 10m in size... is there a way to skirt this limit? I would be happy to accept lower collision fidelity for the larger objects if it meant maintaining optimal performance.

I was thinking that this might have to be achieved by splitting large objects up into multiple "sections" and then tying them together with fixed joints? Is this even a good idea?

Perhaps someone could shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Why don't you post this on the box2D forum. I think you'll get a better response there, since the developer of box2D is frequently posting there.

Answer (score 0):

Box2D is optimized to work with dynamic bodies with dimensions in range: 0.1 - 10. So you can scale your system by 10: make the smallest sheep 0.1 and the largest 20. Your planets will be in this case ~100.

I think you have to try with sizes I suggested. I think it should work well. Also don't make your bodies too massive. Play with their density. When I changed basic density in my project from 10 to 1 the simulation quality increased significantly.

Using fixed joints is not good idea. They are recommend to use only if they are considered breakable. Otherwise using one body with multiple fixtures is preferable.

Comment: Andrew, the point of the matter is that I want a sense of scale in my sim... the difference between 0.1 and 20 isn't enough.. Does putting multiple bodies together with fixed joints work if I want a slow dynamic body of size 50 or larger? Btw this is a space sim.. not a sheep sim :)